# cellForRowAt indexPath not called when give tableview height from contentSize

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, contentsize

I don't not why `cellForRowAt indexPath` not call. I checked `delegate, datasource` it is proper. And I also check with static height then It will work but when I gave tableView height `constant` from tableview content size then I will not call. This is my code.

```
//MARK: View life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblItemList.rowHeight = 76
        tblItemList.estimatedRowHeight =  UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        heightConstraintForTblItem.constant = tblItemList.contentSize.height
    }

extension CheckoutVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arrProductList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    { 
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckOutItemCell", for: indexPath) as! CheckOutItemCell
            if arrProductList.count > 0 {
                let data = arrProductList [indexPath.row]
                cell.lblItemName.text = data.product_name ?? ""
                cell.lblQuantity.text = "\(data.product_total_quantity ?? 0)"
                cell.lblTotalPrice.text = CURRENCY + "\(data.product_total_amount ?? 0.0)"
            }

            return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if tableView == tblItemList {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Comment: Set outlet tableview height like @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraintForTblItem: NSLayoutConstraint!

Comment: if tableview height is less than cell height then it will not called. please check tableview height.

Comment: I think your tableview height is may be zero or less than cell size

Comment: @NiravKotecha No It is proper

Comment: @JaydeepVyas No it is not zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1) Remove `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt` method  and `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`

2) Remove `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method

3) in `ViewDidAppear`

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.heightConstraintForTblItem.constant = self. tblItemList.contentSize.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
```

3)After your API call or when you have data to load in tableview

```
            self.tblItemList.reloadData()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.heightConstraintForTblItem.constant = self. tblItemList.contentSize.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Make sure you have correct constraint given , Make sure you have correctly connected IBOutlet , Double check datasource delegate

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried it with my current code and It will work. I just added         self.view.layoutIfNeeded() in this viewWillLayoutSubviews() method and working fine

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya Yes, But still I am suggesting you to go with entire code I have shared with you because sometime you may face that your tableview is not correctly resized due to some multi threading issue. If you are convinced that your code is working correctly then you don't need to change it :) You can mark answer accepted if you want :)